# I am trying to extract the device ID which is unique for each and every device for react-native using expo,but showing error log

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, deviceid

I have tried the npm package
mom install @react-native-device-info to get the device ID. But showing the error log.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6sh14.jpg)

Using expo i tried the expo-device package where Expo.constants.deviceId , it is generating some id with alphabets,i read in GitHub that "this ID generated will changing each and every time when we uninstall and reinstall the application on the same device". I need the unique I'd which shouldn't be changed even the application is reinstalled in the same device.[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IOQ6W.jpg)

Comment: I have provided the error log img and program img for your reference

Comment: Please format your question better and use code samples to illustrate what you have tried and did not succeed